# Error with input in code even though i have the header file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I tried to run a program that I made but for some reason I got an error when I ran the program. The Error is with the cin >> x >> y part. My main problem right now is that I don't know how to input stuff into the vector by human input. The error I am having is Multiple markers at this line
    -request for member y in y, which is of non-class 
     type int
    -request for member x in x, which is of non-class 
     type int
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};
int manhattan_dist(const Point& p, const Point& q) {
    return abs(p.x - q.x) + abs(p.y - q.y);
}
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Point x,y;
    Rd("marathon.in");
    Wt("marathon.out");
    int checkpoints;
    vector<Point> points(checkpoints);
    int largestdistance=0;
    int sum=0;
    cin >> checkpoints;
    for (int i=0; i<checkpoints; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++){
            cin >> x >> y;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < checkpoints - 1; ++i) {  // stop before c-1, so i and i+1 are valid
        sum += manhattan_dist(points[i], points[i+1]);
    }

    if (sum > largestdistance){
        largestdistance=sum;
    }
    cout << largestdistance << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a coding service.

Comment: remove the commented out code if you don't intend to use it

Comment: you declare `int checkpoints` then initialize a vector of that size but don't say how big the vector should be, because that variable is never set.

Comment: @RyanHaining I have deleted the commented code.

Comment: I have fixed the errors for the flags I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define how `operator>>` should work for your custom type. For that you'll need to overload it.  If you want the first number from `cin` to go to `Point::x` and the other to `Point::y` then the following should work:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Point& p) {
    return in >> p.x >> p.y;
}
```

then

```
Point p;
std::cin >> p;
```

would work.  Then you could push it back onto the `points` vector.  It appears that you're trying to read in a bunch of points from stdin and push them into a vector.  If that's the cast then you'll need to sit in a loop.

```
std::vector<Point> points;
Point p;
while (std::cin >> p) {
    points.push_back(p);
}
```

or, if the `checkpoints` variable is supposed to be initialized as the size of the `points` vector

```
std::vector<Point> points(checkpoints);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    std::cin >> points[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be corrected as

```
cin >> x.x >> y.y;
```

You are accessing a custom defined struct. std::cin is not defined for your struct!
If you need to use it that way you will have to do operator overload.